# Power operator works on vector of length one but not longer?

Tags: r

This code is non-sensical so getting the result isn't the important part, understanding why the two methods arrive at different conclusions is what I'm trying to understand.

```
# data
days <- c(528, 900, 1050, 1300)
returns <- c(-46.9363726590971, 113.096047917561, -55.1435291957069, 251.540399180745) 

# the operation I would like to do; note the NaN for two of them
returns ^ (252 / days)

# pulling out the first values fails in the same way
(returns[1]) ^ (252 / days[1])

# and sapply yields the same result
sapply(X = seq_along(days), FUN = function(i) returns[i] ^ (252 / days[i]))

# just using the numbers gives a different result for the negative numbers
-46.9363726590971 ^ (252 / 528)
113.096047917561 ^ (252/900)
-55.1435291957069 ^ (252/1050)
251.540399180745 ^ (252/1300)
```

Why is this the case?
Thank you

Comment: I presume `vector` is supposed to be `returns`?

Comment: @joran yes, thank you

Comment: It's a floating point thing, I guess. Compare `-46.9363726590971 ^ (252 / 528) # some number` vs `(-46.9363726590971) ^ (252 / 528) # NaN`. As soon as you ask R to hold onto the number, it's going to round it or something.

Comment: @Frank I was debating whether this was floating point or an order of operations thing...depending on when the unary `-` is applied.

Comment: @joran Oh, yeah, I think that must be it, negative number to a weird fraction. `-(46.9363726590971 ^ (252 / 528)) # works`. If OP wants the negative numbers there then... `as.complex(returns) ^ (252 / days)`

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you for your help. Write it as an answer and I'll flag it as such.